# Enforcing encryption rules in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, security, encryption, pymongo

How can I enforce a rule for encryption in mongodb so that any function which involves mongodb operations follows that rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PyMongo Provides
[Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/encryption.html) with samples in its documentation.

Comment: But this is for enterprise edition